# Actionscript to php then to word template and replace variables

Tags: php, actionscript-3, ms-word

I need to write a code which can do following using actionscript:
1. Send the variables to a php
2. php should open a [re designed word document.
3. Specific word document entries should be replaced with the variables sent from actioncript retaining the formatting of the template.
4. Save the document and provide a link for its download OR just mail it to an address.

I have asked few questions before which very pretty simple compared to this and i did not get any answer for it.. I dont know if this will either. If possible please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To send the variables from ActionScript you would need to do something like the following:

```
var http:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
http.url = "http://www.yourWebsite.com/yourPhpFile.php";
http.method = "POST";
var variablesToSend:Object = new Object();
for (var varName:String in yourVariables){
variablesToSend[varName] = yourVariables[varName];
}
http.send(variablesToSend);
```

From "yourPhpFile.php" I would suggest adding some special keywords to search for in the template and do a `str_replace()` with the variables received through the `$_POST` object. I'm no php expert but something like:

```
$yourFilePath = "C:\your\file\path\here.txt";
$yourFileAsString = file_get_contents($yourFilePath);
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
$yourFileAsString = str_replace($key,$value,$yourFileAsString);
}
file_put_contents(genNewFileName(),$yourFileAsString);
```